# TS 2339 error property "x" does not exist on type 'Readonly<Partial<string | Record<string, string | undefined>>>'. property "x" doesnt exist string

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

my code was working until i tried updating all my packages. this was a mistake as my project is class based components instead of hooks and i believe react is moving away from class based components. I tried to revert the updates by copy pasta my package.json from my previous commits and deleting nodemodules and packagelock.json and npm install but that also didnt work.

heres the code.

```
export interface ChannelType{
name?: string
channelId: string
}
import { withRouter, WithRouterProps } from '../../services/withRouter'

interface AuthProps {
sessionToken: string | undefined | null
channel: ChannelType[]
}
class ChannelEntry extends Component<AuthProps & withRouterProps, ChannelEntryState> {
constructor(props: AuthProps & withRouterProps) {
    super(props)
//stuff
}

function = () => {
const { match } = this.props;
fetch(`${APIURL}/channel/${match.params.channelId}/channelentry`, {
        //stuff
}
```

the issue is .channelId. i have a custom HOC withrouter to use match.params because im using class components.

```
import { ComponentType } from 'react';
import { useLocation, useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

export interface WithRouterProps<T = ReturnType<typeof useParams>> {
history: {
 back: () => void;
 goBack: () => void;
 location: ReturnType<typeof useLocation>;
push: (url: string, state?: any) => void;
}
location: ReturnType<typeof useLocation>;
match: {
params: T;
};
navigate: ReturnType<typeof useNavigate>;
}

export const withRouter = <P extends object>(Component: ComponentType<P>) => {
return (props: Omit<P, keyof WithRouterProps>) => {
const location = useLocation();
const match = { params: useParams() };
const navigate = useNavigate();

const history = {
  back: () => navigate(-1),
  goBack: () => navigate(-1),
  location,
  push: (url: string, state?: any) => navigate(url, { state }),
  replace: (url: string, state?: any) => navigate(url, {
    replace: true,
    state
  })
};

return (
  <Component
    history={history}
    location={location}
    match={match}
    navigate={navigate}
    {...props as P}
  />
);
};
};
```

ill be honest and say that i dont really know how this works but it was working until the update. i also dont want to convert everything to hooks because i want atleast one of my projects to be in typescript.

Comment: I don't know if the issue is related to the package updating, but please at least tell which line does the error message refer to. Are you sure it's about `property "x"`? Such property exists nowhere in the code you showed.

Comment: Besides, class components should work perfectly on newer versions of React, even though React doesn't encourage using them for new code. On the other hand, TypeScript has nothing to do with this and can be used with both class components and function components.

Comment: "...I believe react is moving away from class based components" - Understatement of the year. React certainly moved away from Class components years ago ([Feb 2019](https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2019/02/06/react-v16.8.0.html)), when hooks were released in v16.8. Can you [edit] to provide a more infomative description of the issue, the actual and complete error message, and any error stacktrace if one exists? See [mcve].

Comment: the error appears on every line i used channelId on this file. its not a problem on the other files but i only use the match props on this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue is `"channelId"` then I suspect it is the line in `fetch` where the code attempts to access `match.params.channelId`.

The [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params) hook type declaration:

> ```
> declare function useParams<
>   K extends string = string
> >(): Readonly<Params<K>>;
> ```

In other words, it doesn't know about the `channelId` path paremeter.

Since you are not using `useParams` directly where you could write something like `useParams<{ channelId?: string }>();` you should be able to cast the resultant `match.params` object prior to using it.

Example:

```js
function = () => {
  const { match: { params } } = this.props;
  const { channelId } = params as { channelId?: string };

  fetch(`${APIURL}/channel/${channelId}/channelentry`, {
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```